# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Codelens enabled, but not functioning

Tags: visual-studio-2015, codelens

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXM1H.png)I had to reinstall VS2015 and updated to Update 2.   Codelens is present and all checked, but no references are present in any of my solutions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nclyT.png)

I've uploaded an image.... all Codelens checkboxes are checked... bit of a stumper

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the VS2015 Update 2 couple of weeks back and everything works great for me, including CodeLens. Can you please provide a screenshot of the problem you are seeing?

I would suggest you to check your 'CodeLens' settings under Tools -> Options -> All Languages Menu and ensure CodeLens is enabled.

[image]

Comment: EDIT: Tried opening in 'safe mode' to rule out plugins but no change.  I thought perhaps the functionality was redacted from the Enterprise SKU?

Answer (score 0):

The whole `Show References` option is missing for me since I installed Update 2! Apparently so is `Show CodeHealth` - I didn't even know that *was* an option.

VS Version is Enterprise 2015 **v14.0.25123.00 Update 2**
I have many add-ons so I have a sneaking suspicion one of them is interfering here, but was definitely working prior to Update 2.

[image]

Comment: your test and tested by ones are also missing, if you aren't seeing those references AT ALL, like in the screenshot, then something has gone wrong, and it can't find or load those providers (tests, tested by depend on references).  you might need to try `devenv /setup` as admin, or even repair your VS if that is missing.

Comment: For anyone coming across this post, running a "repair" on the Update 2 setup resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't seeing the References indicator **AT ALL** in the settings window, like in the screenshots above, then something has gone very wrong with your VS install, and it can't find or load those CodeLens providers (tests, tested by depend on references).

you might need to try

1. devenv /setup as admin, -or-
2. add/remove programs -> visual studio 2015 -> "modify" or "change" depending on OS version and choose "Repair" from the Visual Studio installer